# Looping through ArrayList in Windows Form and displaying on form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have an `ArrayList` that can have an undetermined number of values. At the moment I have a textbox with multiline populated by a `For` loop to test this is working correctly – it is, and this displays everything correctly. What I really want to do though is output to a label text which has an image next to the label (same image next to each one if that makes a difference). I know I could create labels 1 through 10 on the form and then set them based on the iteration and then display the picture to the left of the label with code, but this seems the wrong way to do it in case the `ArrayList` has say 15 results.

Is there a better way to do this or am I over thinking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create controls dynamically; they’re the same as any other class.

```
Dim l As New Label()
l.Text = "Some text"

Dim p As New PictureBox()
p.Image = My.Resources.someImage

' All container controls have a Controls collection
Me.Controls.Add(l)
Me.Controls.Add(p)
```

The tricky part is positioning them, but a `StackPanel` should help. (You can create `Panel`s to contain each pair in the same way; just add to the `Panel`’s `Controls`, then add the `Panel` to your `StackPanel`.)

Also, don’t use `ArrayList`s! Generic lists are safer and much more flexible. If you have a list of strings, represent them as a [`List(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I had absolutely no idea you could do that, it's perfect. Thanks for your time in replying.